# Remove element from nested array mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i have the following document , it has two array's , one inside the other ,
attachment array and files array inside attachment array . 
i want to delete an element inside files array using this element _id . but its not working with me , i tried this code , it return 
 { n: 144, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }

```
   Invoice.update({}, {
        $pull: {
            "attachment":
            {
                "files":
                {
                    $elemMatch:
                        { _id: ObjectId("5b7937014b2a961d082de9bf") }
                }
            }
        }
    }, { multi: true })
        .then(result => {
            console.log("delete", result);


        });
```

this is how the document looks like 
[image: document]

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet thanks , but the post is different , i have 2 arrays and i want to delete element inside the second array that exist in the first array .

Comment: Try `Invoice.update( 
{}, 
{ "$pull": { "attachment.$[].files":{_id:ObjectId("5b7969ac8fb15f3e5c8e844e") } }}, 
{ "multi": true } , function (err, result) { console.log(result); });`

Comment: { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 } 
{ MongoError: cannot use the part (attachment of attachment.$[].files) to traverse the element ({attachment: []})

Comment: What is your mongo server version ? You need 3.6. Also you may need to run admin command from shell `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: 3.6 or 4.0 depending on your version } )`

Comment: MongoDB shell version v3.4.13
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.13
do i need to run the command?

Comment: You have to first upgrade to 3.6 and run the command on 3.6 shell.

Comment: ok , i will thank you so much for your time sir :) i will let you know what happen

Comment: @Veeram this worked very well !!! thank you so much , please add your answer as an answer so i can confirm it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below update query in 3.6 version.

```
Invoice.update( 
 {}, 
 {"$pull":{"attachment.$[].files":{_id:ObjectId("5b7969ac8fb15f3e5c8e844e")}}}, 
 {"multi": true}, function (err, result) {console.log(result);
});
```

Use `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: 3.6 or 4.0 depending on your version } )` if your are upgrading from old version.

Comment: What if i want to find this file using the id ? 
i tried to do this but it did not work , 
 Invoice.find({
                        "attachment.$[].files": {
                            _id: ObjectId(fileId)
                        }
                    }, function (err, result) {
                        console.log("**", result)
                    });

Comment: Try  `Invoice.find({ "attachment.files": { _id: ObjectId(fileId) } }, function (err, result) { console.log("**", result) });`

Comment: nope it did not work it return empty array , 
i tried this and it work but i am not sure if this is a best way to do it 
Invoice.findOne({
            "attachment.files._id": ObjectId(fileId)

        }, { 'attachment.files.$': 1 }, async function (err, result) {console.log("**",result)});

Answer (score 4):

**For Mongodb version prior to 3.6**

There is only one nested level here so you can simply use  [**`$`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) positional operator.

```
Invoice.update(
  { "attachment.files._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5b7937014b2a961d082de9bf") },
  { "$pull": { "attachment.$.files": { "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5b7937014b2a961d082de9bf") }}},
  { "multi": true }
)
```

**For Mongodb version 3.6 and above**

If you want to update multiple elements inside `attachement` array then you can use [**`$[]`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) the all positional operator.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

Invoice.update(
  { "attachment.files._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5b7937014b2a961d082de9bf") },
  { "$pull": { "attachment.$[].files": { "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5b7937014b2a961d082de9bf") }}},
  { "multi": true }
)
```

And If you want to update single element inside the `attachment` array then you can use [**`$[<identifier>]`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) that identifies the array elements that match the `arrayFilters` conditions.

Suppose you want to update only an element inside `attachment` having `_id` equal to `ObjectId(5b7934f54b2a961d081de9ab)`

```
Invoice.update(
  { "attachment.files._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5b7937014b2a961d082de9bf") },
  { "$pull": { "attachment.$[item].files": { "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5b7937014b2a961d082de9bf") } } },
  { "arrayFilters": [{ "item._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5b7934f54b2a961d081de9ab") }], "multi": true }
)
```

Comment: @Winzlet it did not work .. i got this 
{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }

Comment: You need to cast your id to object id...  Just I did above

Comment: i did like this , same thing .
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
Invoice.update(
            { "attachment.files._id": ObjectId("5b7969ac8fb15f3e5c8e844e") },
            {
                "$pull": {
                    "attachment.$[].files.$[]._id": ObjectId("5b7969ac8fb15f3e5c8e844e")
                }
            },
            { "multi": true }
            , function (err, result) {
                console.log(result);
            });

Comment: @AhmadKhalaf I have updated the answer... Please have a look

Comment: i updated to 3.6 and as Veeram said using the same code you both provided it work perfect ^^ thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue and got another solution:

```
const modelA = await Model.findOne(...)
modelA.array1[0].nestedArray[1] = 'test value'
await modelA.update(modelA.toObject())
```