# MongoDB $pull on deeply nested arrays with multiple matching items

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

We are trying to remove deeply nested array items i.e. array.array.matching_item using the MongoDB $pull operator, however, every attempt has failed. If we use the positional operator it only removes the first match when there may be multiple matches in array.array. We've tried using the $elemMatch too but can't get this to work.

We have document data like this:

```js
{
  _id: 123,
  shipping_lines: [
    {
      _id: 5,
      related_items: [
        {
          name: "George"
        },
        {
          name: "Adam"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      _id: 6,
      related_items: [
        {
          name: "George"
        },
        {
          name: "Tom"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

We are then trying to remove every array item that matches:

```
shipping_lines.related_items.name: "George"
```

The only answers we can find either don't deal with deeply nested arrays or only remove the first matching array item from each document.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51916388/2683814

Comment: @Veeram hadn't come across this post - will give it a shot and come back. Cheers

Comment: @Veeram yep, that's the solution - sorry for the dup - I've marked the question as a dup but can delete if you think this is better?

Comment: this works for me: 


db.getCollection('test').update(
    { _id: 124 },
    { $pull: { 'shipping_lines.0.related_items':{ 'name' : 'George'  } } }
    )

Comment: @Kiwi that would only deal with the first shipping line. The correct solution has already been provided by Veeram

Comment: @Matthew okay.problem was interesting but I hope you generate query at run time you can replace 0 with index element.

Comment: @Kiwi your solution would only deal with one specific array item at a time. As per the QU it has to effect all array items going down.